# What's the meaning of "for all that unwanted attention"?

Tags: meaning

> It is a perfect day for a bike ride. And for wearing fitted sweats afterwards
> to the supermarket for all that unwanted attention.

I'm not sure what she meant here with "for all that unwanted attention". Does it mean to get unwanted attention or to avoid it?

Comment: I suspect it's a joke. If she is wearing 'fitted' (tight) clothes to the supermarket **for** attention, it cannot be unwanted.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for your help. Yeah, I suppose so. This is a comedy show. I think you're right.

Answer (score 4):

She's being sarcastic. She's saying that she is going to wear a tight-fitting sweater that shows off her figure for the purpose of getting unwanted attention. That is, she wants to get "unwanted" attention. She wants men to look at her and think she's beautiful and sexy and then at the same time she will pretend to complain that she doesn't want men looking at her.

Comment: One nitpick: *sweats* are worn on the lower body, while a *sweater* is worn on the upper body. The two are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Martha Yes, sorry, I read "sweats" and thought "sweater".